# Scaling Spark application with adding new clusters

Tags: apache-spark

I have the next SLA for my big data project: regardless amount of concurrent spark tasks, the max execution time shouldn't exceed 5 minutes. For example: there are 10 spark concurrent tasks,
the slowest task shall take < 5 mins, as the number of tasks increases I have to be sure that this time wouldn't exceed 5 mins. Using the usual autoscaling is not appropriate here because adding new nodes takes a couple of minutes and it doesn't solve a problem with the exponential growth of tasks (e.g. skew from 10 concurrent tasks to 30 concurrent tasks).

I came across the idea to spin up a new cluster on demand so meet the SLA requirements. Let's say, I found the max number of the concurrent tasks (all of them are almost equal and take the same resources) which can be executed simultaneously on my cluster within 5 mins e.g. - 30 tasks. when the number of tasks approaches the threshold, the new cluster will be spinned up. The idea of this pattern is to struggle slowness during autoscaling and meet the SLA.

My question is next: are there any alternative options to my pattern except autoscaling on a single cluster (it's not suitable for my usecase because of slowness of my spark provider).